# Replacing characters in Python string

Tags: python, string, sqlalchemy, teradata, str-replace

I'm trying to clean a list that is essentially a Table definition I pulled from Teradata DB using SQLAlchemy. I'm essentially trying to replace the \r character from the string

I've tried using the replace function in a for loop as shown below

```
import teradata
import sqlalchemy
import string


eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradatasql:///?user=xxxx&       

# execute sql
query = 'SHOW TABLE DBADMIN_BKP.LIKP_BKP'
result = eng.execute(query)
results = result.fetchall()
results = [items.replace("\n", "") for items in results]

print (results)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SQL_ALCHEMY.py", line 12, in <module>
results = [items.str_replace("\n", "") for items in results]
File "SQL_ALCHEMY.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
results = [items.str_replace("\n", "") for items in results]
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'replace'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `items` is a string? I would suggest inspecting what the elements of `results` actually are.

Comment: Could you post some of `items` to be sure of what you're doing?

Comment: This is a sample of the data being assigned to the variable:
[("CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBADMIN_BKP.LIKP_BKP ,NO FALLBACK ,\r     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,\r     NO AFTER JOURNAL,\r     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,\r     DEFAULT ME ... (12819 characters truncated) ... HARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,\r      FSH_VAS_CG CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL, \rPRIMARY KEY ( MANDT ,VBELN ))\r;",)]

Comment: The above data is the result of print (results)

Comment: I've managed to convert the list into a string now and now am trying to use the replace function like so:
results = results.replace('\r', '')
The code passes without error but the dreaded \r is still there :(

Comment: Whats frustrating is that its working for other characters in the string but not for \r

Comment: You should edit your question to include these updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix to your code that should make it work. I'm pretty sure you just misused the `.replace()` function in your code. Here is the correct code:

```
import teradata
import sqlalchemy
import string


eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradatasql:///?user=xxxx&')

# execute sql
query = 'SHOW TABLE DBADMIN_BKP.LIKP_BKP'
result = eng.execute(query)
results = result.fetchall()
results = results.replace("\n", "") #This is the segment of the code that was causing the error. 

print (results)
```

Comment: this is the error I get after I tried your suggestion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQL_ALCHEMY.py", line 13, in <module>
    results = results.replace("\n", "")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I've managed to convert the list into a string now and now am trying to use the replace function like so: results = results.replace('\r', '') The code passes without error but the dreaded \r is still there :(

Comment: Whats frustrating is that its working for other characters in the string but not for \r

Answer (score 0):

The item contained in your list is a tuple.

If you print results[0] you'll get:

```
('CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBADMIN_BKP.LIKP_BKP ,NO FALLBACK ,\r NO BEFORE JOURNAL,\r NO AFTER JOURNAL,\r CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,\r DEFAULT ME ... (12819 characters truncated) ... HARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,\r FSH_VAS_CG CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL, \rPRIMARY KEY ( MANDT ,VBELN ))\r;',)
```

Now you've said that you've turned that into a string, which I assume you did by doing str(results[i]). This produces:

```
"('CREATE MULTISET TABLE DBADMIN_BKP.LIKP_BKP ,NO FALLBACK ,\\r NO BEFORE JOURNAL,\\r NO AFTER JOURNAL,\\r CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,\\r DEFAULT ME ... (12819 characters truncated) ... HARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,\\r FSH_VAS_CG CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL, \\rPRIMARY KEY ( MANDT ,VBELN ))\\r;',)"
```

When it got transformed into a string, Python wanted to ensure that "\r" would *actually* be printed, rather than the meaning of the escape sequence "\r", which is a carriage return. In order to do this, another backslash is added, giving the escape sequence "\\" which literally represents a single "\"

```
>>> print("\\r")
\r
>>> print("\r")

>>> print("\\")
\
>>> print("\")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("\")
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

So in order to remove this "\\r" character, you need to identify it properly.